# How to compare elements inside List of strings with Array List of string?

Tags: java, selenium, automation

I have added products to my basket and listed their URL in a List and want to verify these products against given String[] of products 
the items are stored backwards in z String[] so the last item here is the 1st item in the List .. the number of items is 3 and below code works for 2 items and throw invoker exception at the assert method in the third item

```
public void verifyBag(String[] goods) {
    actions.clickOn(By.xpath(bagLocator));
    Arrays.sort(goods);
    List<WebElement> listItems = actions.driver.findElements(By.xpath(bagItems));
    List <String> actualItems = new ArrayList<String>();
    for(int i=0;i<listItems.size();i++)
    {
        actualItems.add(listItems.get(i).getAttribute("href"));
    }
    int j = goods.length-1;
    for(int i=0;i<goods.length;i++) 
    { 

        String actualItem = actualItems.get(i);
        String product = goods[j];
        System.out.println(product);
        //assertTrue(actualItems.get(i).contains(goods[j]));
        assertTrue(actualItem.equals(product));
            j--;        
        } 
        assertEquals(listItems.size(), goods.length,"Assert Number of Items in the Bag");
    }
```

Comment: *and throw invoker exception at the assert method in the third item* ... please share the stacktrace and details of the line where it throws the exception

Comment: Firstly, I think you should check for quantity before you do the looping. Secondly, there is `list.contains()` available, which you might be able to use. Thirdly, if you just want to know if everything is correct, you can convert the array into a list, then sort both, and use `equals()`.

Comment: By the way, after the first three lines, your code can be well optimized for readability as `List<String> actualItems = listItems.stream()
                .map(listItem -> listItem.getAttribute("href"))
                .collect(Collectors.toList());
        IntStream.range(0, goods.length).forEach(i -> assertEquals(goods[goods.length - i - 1], actualItems.get(i)));
        assertEquals(listItems.size(), goods.length, "Assert Number of Items in the Bag");`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you don't care about the order, but about the match between provided list of `goods` and `actualItems`, you can do this:

1. Convert input array `String[] goods` into some collection, for example `List`. Lets call it `goodsList`.
2. From `goodsList`, remove all items that are also in `actualItems`.

   - If resulting set is empty, it means all items from `goodsList` are
     also in `actualItems`.
   - If resulting set is not empty, it will contain list of items that are missing in `actualItems` comparing to `goodsList`
3. You can also do the reverse: from `actualItems`, remove all items that are also contained in `goodsList`. That gives you list of items that were not present in provided list.

Code:

```
public void verifyBag(String[] goods) {
    actions.clickOn(By.xpath(bagLocator));
    List<WebElement> listItems = actions.driver.findElements(By.xpath(bagItems));
    List <String> actualItems = new ArrayList<String>();
    for(int i=0;i<listItems.size();i++)
    {
        actualItems.add(listItems.get(i).getAttribute("href"));
    }
    List<String> goodsList = new ArrayList(Arrays.asList(goods));
    goodsList.removeAll(actualItems);
    if(goodsList.size() == 0) {
        // All goods from provided goods list are also in actualItems
    }
    else {
        // Some items didn't match
    }
```

Comment: I tried your cod @Kiril but it threw the below exception

java.lang.UnsupportedOperationException
 at java.util.AbstractList.remove(AbstractList.java:161)
 at java.util.AbstractList$Itr.remove(AbstractList.java:374)
 at java.util.AbstractCollection.removeAll(AbstractCollection.java:376)
 at POM.NisnassProduct.verifyBag(NisnassProduct.java:72)

Comment: apparently it's a known issue with Arrays.asList. I updated a code to work around it

Answer (score 0):

1. You have to check the size of `goods` and `actualItems` before doing the loop. Make sure that array and list have the same size and both of them is not null or empty.
2. Function `listItems.get(i)` and `getAttribute("href")` can return a null value, please check it before add to list.